# PWA React app is not rendering after running on Docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to place a React PWA application in docker container.
So I have created an image for the app based on the Dockerfile below.
Once I create the container, it starts successfully but in the browser I only see white page without any errors printed in the console.
I would be happy if someone know what the problem can be and give me a solution or suggestion.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Create Docker Image example code

> docker build -t pwa-react .

Run Docker Container example code

> docker run -it  -p 3001:3001 --rm --name pwa-react pwa-react

Comment: Please add your `docker run` command to your post

Comment: Alright, I edit my post. Now it is included